# fullpage.js and materialize.js; using the materialize sidenav disable mouse scrolling

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js, materialize

I have trouble in getting materialze.js and fullpage.js working together.  Here is an [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/netzego/cwsu9q53/) to demonstrate the problem.  Fullpage.js is setup to jump in responsive mode at 640px.  In normal-mode (641px and above) everythings works as expected.  In responsive-mode everythings works fine, as long the Slideout-Menu (materialize.js) is not used.  After the Slideout-Menu is been used, mouse-scrolling stopped completely.  While keyboard-scrolling works fine.

See [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/netzego/cwsu9q53/)

**materialize markup**

```
<nav id="nav">
  <ul id="sidenav" class="side-nav">
    <li data-menuanchor="a"><a href="#a">a</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="b"><a href="#b">b</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="c"><a href="#c">c</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="d"><a href="#d">d</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="e"><a href="#e">e</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="quick-links" class="right">
    <li data-menuanchor="b"><a href="#b">b</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="c"><a href="#c">c</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="sidenav-toggle" data-activates="sidenav" href="#!">menu</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**fullpage markup**

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div id="sa" class="section">a</div>
  <div id="sb" class="section">b</div>
  <div id="sc" class="section">c</div>
  <div id="sd" class="section">d</div>
  <div id="se" class="section">e</div>
</div>
```

**materialized js**

```
$("#sidenav-toggle").sideNav({
    closeOnClick: true
});
```

**fullpage js**

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    menu: '#nav',
    anchors: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    normalScrollElements: '#nav',
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0,
    responsiveWidth: 640
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Materialize menu [is somehow removing the `overflow: visible;` property applied to the `body` element](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/js/sideNav.js#L79) by `fullpage.js` on responsive mode.

Just add it again when closing the menu:

```
$(document).on('click', '.drag-target', function(e) {
     //in responsive mode?
     if($('.fp-responsive').length){
         $('body').css('overflow', 'visible');
     }

});
```

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/cwsu9q53/51/)

Comment: Yes, it does the trick. I also add `#sidenav` to the event-listener. `$(document).on('click', '.drag-target, #sidenav', function(e) { ... });` thanks, you made my day.

Comment: Of course you'll need to add the `#sidenav` selector only if you use the material menu with the option `closeOnClick: true` like in my example.